# Running a bash scrip file manually (via the terminal) produces a different result that when running it on bash?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I'm writing a bash script to monitor the disk space usage via the disk percentages.

usage.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
NUMARRAY=$(df --output=pcent | sed '1d;s/^ //;s/%//')
ARR=( $NUMARRAY )

for hddPercentageUsage in "${ARR[@]}"; do
         #echo $hddPercentageUsage;
         if((hddPercentageUsage >= 50)); then
                echo 'Half of disk space is taken up'
         fi
done
```

The command

```
df --output=pcent | sed '1d;s/^ //;s/%//'
```

produces something like this and I just basically loop through that string:

```
 1
 1
78
 0
 0
 0
 0
 1
```

If I run it manually (via terminal) the script produces the correct results.
Iif I run it via the 'crontab -e' command it doesn't produce the result 'Half of disk space is taken up' (when one of the disks takes up more than 50% usage)

Cronjob command

```
*/5 * * * * /home/ubuntu/space_log/./usage.sh > /home/ubuntu/space_log/space.log
```

Any help guys? Thanks

Comment: It'd be helpful to log stderr, not just stdout -- *especially* if you ran with `set -x` to log commands as they're run.

Comment: BTW, using string-splitting to form an array is not a particularly good practice (you get various other side effects such as glob expansion at the same time). If I were writing this, I'd probably use a `while read` loop to consume content directly from `df` into the shell -- see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: (While I'm kibitzing, another aside -- using a `.sh` extension on a script that's only compatible with bash, *not* sh, isn't particularly good practice. Consider avoiding extensions for executables altogether -- you don't run `ls.elf`, after all).

Comment: (that said, the `set -x` suggestion, like the one to log stderr, wasn't just kibitzing -- that's an actual "if you do this we might be able to answer your question").

Comment: @CharlesDuffy where/how do I log stderr? Thanks!

Comment: `2>/path/to/err.log`. And btw, if you don't want to add `set -x` to the contents of your script, you can add the `-x` to the command line, as in `bash -x yourscript >out.log 2>err.log`. Or, if you want to do the redirection after the script is started, you can add `exec 2>/path/to/err.log` as a command inside the script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy God damn it. This was the problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45781/shell-script-fails-syntax-error-unexpected . I had an empty newline between the top of the file and the shebang. Doing the error logging your recommended gave 'Syntax error: “(” unexpected' . Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help! As an aside, the answer there is *slightly* inaccurate that it's not the kernel choosing `sh` -- the kernel refuses to execute a command without a valid executable header or script shebang at all, but if you're running it from a shell, *that shell* will often attempt to interpret a file marked executable that the kernel doesn't handle as a script. dash does indeed use another copy of `sh` as the default in that case, but the POSIX sh standard doesn't specify an exact behavior, so it varies from shell to shell -- bash will run such shells with bash, zsh runs them with sh, etc.

Comment: ...that difference is why you'll see something like `find . -exec ./somescript {} +` fail to execute a script without a shebang, when `./somescript` works fine.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest that you either edit this question to show how to reproduce the problem (and then answer it yourself), or delete the question. (There's a close-vote option for "caused by a typo", but it takes more time to wait for other folks to vote rather than just deleting the question yourself as the OP; also, if you self-delete, you can later edit the deleted question and reopen it if you choose to).